# How do I copy a file using a wildcard in Windows without appending?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have an excel file that I download from an vendor FTP site on a daily basis.  Every day the file name changes to contain the date and the vendor appends either "actual" or "estimate" to the end of the file.

example:
F_02262014_actual.xlsx
F_02262014_estimate.xlsx
etc.

Because of these slight changes, I'm using a wildcard to copy the file to a consistent name in another directory.

Example:
copy \Source\F_02262014* \Target\CurrentFile.xlsx

My problem is that whenever I use a wildcard in the copy command, Windows assumes I'm appending several files to one.  This causes the file to get corrupted (all contents deleted for some reason).

Is there a command, or series of commands, that will copy the first file matching the file pattern to the desired file name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce your reported problem.

DO you mean the source file is emptied, or that the target is empty?

I'd add the `/b` switch to the `COPY`

```
copy /B \Source\F_02262014* \Target\CurrentFile.xlsx
```

...worked for me!

Comment: the resulting file has no data and won't open in excel.  The /B switch seems to work

Comment: when i say has no data, i mean the resulting file has size 1K when the source was 157K, and when i open in text editor it's all garbage.  It won't open in excel.  The /B switch seems to work

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%f in ("\Source\F_02262014*") do copy /y "%%~ff" "\Target\CurrentFile.xlsx"
```

Written to include in batch file. If this will be executed from command line, replace all `%%` with `%`